# ffmpeg split | merge video voice not sync

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

**there are what i done:**

1. download a full mp4 file.
2. due to it's watermark(0s-10s), i split the full video into 2 parts from 10second. the first part with watermark.
3. use ffmpeg delogo the first part.
4. merge the two video into a full again.

> ```
> wget -O download.mp4
> ffmpeg -i download.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -t 00:00:10 tmp1.mp4
> ffmpeg -i download.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:10 tmp2.mp4
> ffmpeg -i tmp1.mp4 -vf "delogo=x=432:y=44:w=1060:h=108" -c:a copy tmp3.mp4
> echo file tmp3.mp4 > mergelist.txt && echo file tmp2.mp4 >> mergelist.txt
> ffmpeg -f concat -i mergelist.txt -c copy output.mp4
> ```

**problem i faced:**
**in the last merged video, only one tmp part is fine, the other's video and voice not sync and play time more faster than before.**

why i divide it, delogo(although only the first 10 seconds shows) full video more than 1h, re-encode takes much time, 10s part fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
ffmpeg -i download.mp4 -vf "delogo=enable='lte(t,10)':x=432:y=44:w=1060:h=108" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

I'm assuming `delogo` filter is timeline editing enabled.

Comment: Appreciate! Solved, these 2 video have different timescale so with -video_track_timescale force the tbn and then merge as before works!